# How to fix Visual Studio Error MSB4018

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, .net-assembly

I am getting the following error (MSB4018) with Visual Studio 2012 Express AND Community 2015. I also get the error when trying to build x86 Assembly Language AND C++.

```
Error   1   error MSB4018: The "Link" task failed unexpectedly.
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.FileTracker' threw an exception. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: There are no more files. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070012)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.NativeMethodsShared.ThrowExceptionForErrorCode(Int32 errorCode)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.NativeMethodsShared.GetLongFilePath(String path)
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.FileTracker..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.DependencyTableCache.FormatNormalizedTlogRootingMarker(ITaskItem[] tlogFiles)
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.CanonicalTrackedOutputFiles.ConstructOutputTable()
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.CanonicalTrackedOutputFiles.InternalConstruct(ITask ownerTask, ITaskItem[] tlogFiles, Boolean constructOutputsFromTLogs)
   at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.ComputeOutOfDateSources()
   at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.SkipTaskExecution()
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__1.MoveNext()  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  611 5   Project
```

I have tried all the solutions I came across online, and none of them worked. Please help!

Comment: Need more details about everything.  For example, edit your post with the command line to the linker.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by 'the command line to the linker?' How can I open that in VS? I should also note that my Properties are fine. I copied all the files from my other computer where it worked fine. I just installed Visual Studio on this computer so I'm thinking that's the origin

Comment: It looks like MSBuild is crashing. Uninstall any third party extensions you may have installed, and do a repair install of Visual Studio.

Comment: Step 1: Highlight the your question in the browser.  Right Click.   Pick "Search Google"   There's your answer.

Comment: Step 2: Do the above BEFORE you submit a question to Stack Overflow.   You will be happier.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?  Seems to be an MSBuild problem.

Comment: Dale: as stated in the question, I have already searched--and tried--and all the solutions I was able to find did not work for me.

Comment: legalize: sorry about that, I was in a hurry posting

Comment: In one of the option pages in Visual Studio is the Linker options.  One of the pages shows the command line.  Copy the command line text to the clipboard then paste to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue myself. Although my solution is a bit unorthodox, it did the trick. I have another laptop with Visual Studio installed on it that works fine. So I simply copied my files from **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\"** to this computer. I also copied **"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\"** . As stated in a comment, the issue seemed to be with MSBuild. Therefore, it is possible that only that directory's files were invalid. A proper reinstall of Visual Studio may also solve the problem though.